# How to always pass 'render' parameters in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a website where some parameters need to be passed to the frontend for every page that's loaded (ie text that's used in a navbar that is on everypage). At the moment I'm just including all the parameters in every `render` line but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it (in middleware for example). The two parameters below are being used in every `render`.

```
return res.render('index', {
    docTitle: i18n.__('home'),
    isLoggedIn: req.session.isLoggedIn,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own render function, where you set the default values and delegate to `res.render`:

```
const customResRender = (req, res, page, params = {}) => 
  res.render(page, {
    docTitle: i18n.__('home'),
    isLoggedIn: req.session.isLoggedIn,
    ...params
  });
```

Then, use it instead of `res.render`:

```
app.get("/someHandler", (req, res) => {
  // ...
  customResRender(req, res, "index");
});
```